# Copying a vis-network network to another canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, vis.js, drawimage, vis.js-network

I am implementing a 'loupe' ie. a "magnifying glass" that follows the mouse pointer. A portion of a vis-network graph is shown enlarged within the loupe (so that you can see a detail without zooming into the whole network).  I do this by creating an off-screen vis-network with the same nodes and edges and the same viewpoint as the visible network, but at three times the scale.  I then use a `canvas` `drawImage` to copy a portion of the canvas of this larger network into a `div` that floats above the visible network, and which is centred on the mouse pointer.  This all works very well, except that I have a problem lining up the magnified image with the portion of the visible map that is being enlarged.

In my first attempt, the part of the map shown enlarged was a long way away from the location of the mouse pointer on the visible map.  But a process of tedious experimentation, I managed to work out that I needed  a multiplier (which I have called the `magicNumber` in the code below) to get it approximately right, i.e. so that the loupe shows an magnified view of the bit of the network under the pointer.  I expect that this magic number is actually some constant in vis-network, but I can't think what it would be - and the correct value is probably not exactly the 1.92 that I obtained by experiment.

My question therefore is: what should this number be, and what does it mean?

There is a MVE here https://codepen.io/micrology/pen/eYBbKVX

Here is an extract from my code - first the CSS for the loupe and then the JavaScript:

```css
.magnifier {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px black solid;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #1e1e1e;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

```js
    const magSize = 300; // diameter of loupe
    const magnification = 3; // magnification
    let main = elem('main');  // div holding the visible network
    let mainRect = main.getBoundingClientRect();
    let magnifier = document.createElement('canvas');  // the 'magnifying glass'
    magnifier.width = magSize;
    magnifier.height = magSize;
    magnifier.className = 'magnifier';
    let magnifierCtx = magnifier.getContext('2d');
    magnifierCtx.fillStyle = 'white';
    main.appendChild(magnifier);
    let bigNetPane = null;
    let bigNetwork = null;
    let bigNetCanvas = null;
    const magicNumber = 1.92;  / the mysterious magic number

// the loupe pops up when the user holds down the SHIFT key and moves the mouse

    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.shiftKey) createMagnifier();
    });
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
        if (e.shiftKey) showMagnifier(e);
    });
    window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
        if (e.key == 'Shift') closeMagnifier();
    });

    function createMagnifier() {
        if (bigNetPane) {
            bigNetwork.destroy();
            bigNetPane.remove();
        }
        // the triple sized version of the netowrk is generated inside the bigNetPane div, which is off screen
        bigNetPane = document.createElement('div');
        bigNetPane.id = 'big-net-pane';
        bigNetPane.style.position = 'absolute';
        bigNetPane.style.top = '-9999px';
        bigNetPane.style.left = '-9999px';
        bigNetPane.style.width = `${netPane.offsetWidth * magnification}px`;
        bigNetPane.style.height = `${netPane.offsetHeight * magnification}px`;
        main.appendChild(bigNetPane);
        bigNetwork = new Network(bigNetPane, data, options);
        bigNetCanvas = bigNetPane.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
        bigNetwork.moveTo({
            position: network.getViewPosition(),
            scale: magnification * network.getScale(),
        });
        main.style.cursor = 'none';
        magnifier.style.display = 'none';
    }

    function showMagnifier(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (bigNetCanvas == null) createMagnifier(e);
        magnifierCtx.fillRect(0, 0, magSize, magSize);
// this is where the magicNumber is required to line up the enlarged image with where the pointer is
        magnifierCtx.drawImage(
            bigNetCanvas,
            (e.x - mainRect.x) * magicNumber * magnification,
            (e.y - mainRect.y) * magicNumber * magnification,
            magSize,
            magSize,
            0,
            0,
            magSize,
            magSize
        );
        magnifier.style.top = e.clientY - mainRect.y - magSize / 2 + 'px';
        magnifier.style.left = e.clientX - mainRect.x - magSize / 2 + 'px';
        magnifier.style.display = 'block';
    }


    function closeMagnifier() {
        if (bigNetPane) {
            bigNetwork.destroy();
            bigNetPane.remove();
        }
        main.style.cursor = 'default';
        magnifier.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

Comment: From what you've written it would be more probable that the magic number should be 3 but I'm afraid we can't really help you here without seeing a working example of your code that clearly shows the behaviour.

Comment: There is now a minimal example to play with at <https://codepen.io/micrology/pen/eYBbKVX>

Answer (score 0):

I have now got it to work.  The CodePen demo has been edited so it now works as desired.  The corrected code snippet (to compare with the code in the question) is:

```js
const magSize = 300; // diameter of loupe
const magnification = 3; // magnification
const halfMagSize = magSize / 2.0;
let main = elem("mynetwork");
let mainRect = main.getBoundingClientRect();
let magnifier = document.createElement("canvas");
magnifier.width = magSize;
magnifier.height = magSize;
magnifier.className = "magnifier";
let magnifierCtx = magnifier.getContext("2d");
magnifierCtx.fillStyle = "white";
main.appendChild(magnifier);
let bigNetPane = null;
let bigNetwork = null;
let bigNetCanvas = null;
let netPaneCanvas = container.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;

window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.shiftKey) createMagnifier();
});
window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (e.shiftKey) showMagnifier(e);
});
window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if (e.key == "Shift") closeMagnifier();
});

function showMagnifier(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (bigNetCanvas == null) createMagnifier(e);
  magnifierCtx.fillRect(0, 0, magSize, magSize);
  magnifierCtx.drawImage(
    bigNetCanvas,
    ((e.clientX - mainRect.x) * bigNetCanvas.width) /
      netPaneCanvas.clientWidth -
      halfMagSize,
    ((e.clientY - mainRect.y) * bigNetCanvas.height) /
      netPaneCanvas.clientHeight -
      halfMagSize,
    magSize,
    magSize,
    0,
    0,
    magSize,
    magSize
  );
  magnifier.style.top = e.clientY - halfMagSize + "px";
  magnifier.style.left = e.clientX - halfMagSize + "px";
  magnifier.style.display = "block";
}

function createMagnifier() {
  if (bigNetPane) {
    bigNetwork.destroy();
    bigNetPane.remove();
  }
  network.storePositions();
  bigNetPane = document.createElement("div");
  bigNetPane.id = "big-net-pane";
  bigNetPane.style.position = "absolute";
  bigNetPane.style.top = "-9999px";
  bigNetPane.style.left = "-9999px";
  bigNetPane.style.width = `${main.offsetWidth * magnification}px`;
  bigNetPane.style.height = `${main.offsetHeight * magnification}px`;
  main.appendChild(bigNetPane);
  bigNetwork = new vis.Network(bigNetPane, data, {
    physics: { enabled: false }
  });
  bigNetCanvas = bigNetPane.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
  bigNetwork.moveTo({
    position: network.getViewPosition(),
    scale: network.getScale() * magnification,
    animation: false
  });
  main.style.cursor = "none";
  magnifier.style.display = "none";
}
function closeMagnifier() {
  if (bigNetPane) {
    bigNetwork.destroy();
    bigNetPane.remove();
  }
  main.style.cursor = "default";
  magnifier.style.display = "none";
}
```